# Nearest / Fastest Point using OSRM

Tags: routing, open-source-routing-machine

How can I use OSRM to given a destination and 5 origins. Then OSRM should return the fastest origin, the distance between this origin and the destination and the duration of the route.

Can I do it with Table service? And how can I do it?

Comment: the docs for the [*table* API](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/docs/nodejs/api.md#table) (for Node) is fairly comprehensive; add all 6 lonlat pairs as `coordinates`, specifiy which of those are the sources and which one is the destination (by passing their array index as `sources` and `destinations`) and fire it up.

Answer (score 0):

Table Service worked for me. The destination is first -46.890702,-23.199130 and the others 2 points are origins.

```
http://localhost/table/v1/driving/-46.890702,-23.199130;-46.890557,-23.201527;-46.9142061,-23.1895509?sources=1;2&destinations=0&annotations=distance,duration
```